# Boot from Hard Drive via USB but not directly?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

I'm having a bizarre problem, and it seems I'm not alone.

On a Dell Latitude 13, I get the error message "internal hard disk drive not found" during POST.

Yet, if I take the very same hard drive and connect it via a USB drive dock, it boots just fine.

There were clear (now apparently unrelated) problems with the motherboard on this laptop, so I have replaced it.  I have also replaced the SATA controller daughterboard.

It seems there are others facing this issue, but I don't see a solution.  In fact I'm having trouble even understanding what the problem is.

Comment: So what is your question? It sounds like the SATA controller on the board is faulty and you replaced it. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Dell diagnostics. Usually pressing F12 durning boot will allow you to run this.  Thjis would identify the problem component

Comment: We did this.  It shows no problems.